# If I wanted to not use NULL, how would I normalize this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, database-normalization

```
line_item (id, description, parent_id, product_id);
product (id, model);
```

**Example Hierarchy of Line Items**

```
Product A       //"parent" "line item"
    Option 1    //child "line item"s of "parent"
    Option 2
```

**Current DB Data**

```
line_item:
id | description | parent_id | product_id
-----------------------------------------
 1 |   Product A |      NULL |         20  //has no parent "line item"
 2 |    Option 1 |         1 |         -1  //no product associated with option
 3 |    Option 2 |         1 |         -1  //has "line item" parent with id == 1
```

```
product
id | model
--------------
20 | Product A
```

**Question**

I am not exactly sure how to get rid of "NULL" from `parent_id`.  Note that I use `-1` in my `product_id` as well, where I use it in a similar way, saying "there is no "product" or "parent" associated with that particular line item record.

Do I *need* to get rid of it in the first place?

Comment: Does every product have options? Can options have sub options?

Comment: In practice, every "line item" can have its own options because in reality ... we use "parent line items", which are not always products at all.  Most often they are but not always.  Options do not have sub-options.

Comment: Then I see no need for a hierarchie table. One table for the "parent line items", one for the "option line items".

Comment: in situations like this, I've found two perfectly fine options.

First, as many others have said, leave NULL in place.  As long as the NULL value is a sparse value (infrequently occuring) then you're indexing won't be fragmented (even though NULL values can't actually fragment an index).

Second, because I'm an odd-ball, I like to make the parent_ID the same as the record ID value.  If ID = Parent_ID then I'm top level.  No Nulls.  Everyone wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should replace -1 with null. That is a completely legit value.

Null-values actually don't play a role when considering normalization, because you can only speak of functional dependency if you have non-null-values, so you don't have to worry about normalization, your table is fine.

Your table is an implementation of a "disjunct is-a"-relation, that means, that a line_item is either an "option"-line (with the value `parent_id`) or a "product"-line (with the value `product_id` and e.g. `quantity`, ...) and has the common values `id` and `description`. Disjunct means it can't be both at the same time, so the columns for the other type are set to null (that is why you "have to" replace -1 with null).

The usual implementation of a "disjunct is-a" is to add a `type`-column, that defines which of these possibilities it is (the reason is more of a practical kind, e.g. for constraint-checks). You don't need it here, since it is clear to you what kind of line it is without this field, but I added it to emphasize what you are actually implementing and that you did everything in a standard way:

```
line_item:
id | description | line_type | parent_id | product_id
-----------------------------------------------------
 1 |   Product A |   Product |      NULL |         20  
 2 |    Option 1 |    Option |         1 |       NULL  
 3 |    Option 2 |    Option |         1 |       NULL
```

Last remark: There are other possible implementations of "is-a", some of them are getting rid of the null (while introducing other problems), but for disjunct options, this is the usual one. But since it would answer your original question ("If I wanted to not use null..."), I'll add this one too:

```
line_item:
id | description 
-----------------
 1 |   Product A 
 2 |    Option 1 
 3 |    Option 2 


line_item_product:
line_item_id | product_id
---------------------------
           1 |         20  

line_item_option:
line_item_id |  parent_id
---------------------------
           2 |          1 
           3 |          1
```

You have a table for the common columns (for both types `option` and `product`) and a seperate table for the two possibilities with their specific columns.

This would get rid of your null.

The biggest practical problem with this is, that you have to have a more complicated check for the "primary key" in the two tables `line_item_option` and `line_item_product`: You are not allowed to add line 1 in `line_item_option` when it already is in `line_item_product`, but mysql has no easy check for that. That's why this kind of splitting is only used when you have a "non-disjunct is-a"-relation (e.g. if the lines could be both product and option at the same time).

Comment: Thanks!.  Now, your rep is 666, and you have 6 bronze badges. This is like reading advice from the devil!

Comment: now that you've moved away from evil, I can accept & upvote without disturbing your evil ways haha I am kidding of course I hope you know that

Answer (score 1):

NULL is a correct way to represent no value.

In addition, for good practices, if you add a foreign key on the field parent_id that references the parent line_item, or product_id references product you couldn't use -1.

Comment: thanks.  I did not quite understand the "couldn't use -1".  parent_id is a self-referencing foreign key, indicating which row in the same table is considered a "parent" of a particular line item.  When there is no parent, it is set to `-1`, or could be set to `NULL` instead.

Comment: You can set a [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to make sure all the data in the table are coherent. You can't set -1 in the field if you don't have a row with the id -1 (mysql throw error). NULL is more reliable and respect standards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to keep the NULLs intact because it can be used as an indicator of what records are top level items.  Also, the tables already appear to be normalized so normalization isn't relevant to your issue.